# iPhone: How to determine if thread is main thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to determine if the current thread inside a method is a main thread, or just a thread that is asynchronous and created? Does the ID tell me?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Like this: `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: Alternative way:                                                     -(BOOL)IsMainThread
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue() == dispatch_get_current_queue();
}

Comment: `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated as of iOS 6.

Comment: **For Swift 3**
`if Thread.isMainThread {
    print("Main Thread")
}`